# Where to find (free) training in reverse engineering?

Tags: obfuscation, cryptography

Can someone give a list of websites with good (and free) reverse engineering training exercises ?

Comment: http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-should-book-tutorial-questions-be-dealt-with

Comment: @perror: Kris Kaspersky did offer something like that some time ago.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The organisation OpenSecurityTraining offers [free training materials](http://opensecuritytraining.info/Training.html) under creative commons type licenses. Many of the training's are [videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/OpenSecurityTraining/videos?view=1&flow=grid), while others are slide decks and related class materials (scripts, malware samples and so on). The course-ware comes under 3 categories and features the following items (Which I have edited to include the RE related material):

**Beginner:**

- [Introductory Intel x86](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL038BE01D3BAEFDB0): Architecture, Assembly, Applications, & Alliteration
- [Introduction to ARM](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUFkSN0XLZ-n91t_AX5zO007Giz1INwPd)
- [The Life of Binaries](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUFkSN0XLZ-n_Na6jwqopTt1Ki57vMIc3)
- [Malware Dynamic Analysis](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUFkSN0XLZ-kqYbGpY4Gt_VATd4ytQg-Z)
- [Introduction to Trusted Computing](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUFkSN0XLZ-kBgdLhorJD6BR66D5kGoUV)

**Intermediate:**

- [Intermediate Intel x86](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8F8D45D6C1FFD177): Architecture, Assembly, Applications, & Alliteration
- [Introduction to Software Exploits](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL96AB65DFCE02EE3E)
- [Exploits 2: Exploitation in the Windows Environment](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9F9E52502327B1CA)

**Advanced:**

- [Rootkits: What they are, and how to find them](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF58FB7BCB20ED11A)
- [Introduction to Reverse Engineering Software](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUFkSN0XLZ-nXcDG89jS9iqKBnNHmz7Qw)
- Reverse Engineering Malware
- Advanced x86: Virtualization with Intel VT-x

Disclosure: I am not associated with OpenSecurityTraining in any way and have only worked through a small portion of their total offerings. Seems like a great resource though.

Answer (score 21):

Here are my favorite. I started with Lena's tutorials, they are really awesome.

- [tuts4you](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.19) - an endless amount of tutorials. I can highly recommend [Lena's reversing for newbies](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17)
- [binary-auditing](http://www.binary-auditing.com/) - Free IDA Pro Binary Auditing Training Material for University Lectures

Answer (score 16):

The Legend of R4ndom has a long series on a variety of reversing topics. <strike>http://thelegendofrandom.com/blog/sample-page</strike>
http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/sample-page.html

Comment: These tutorials are awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the link is now dead.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150526025225/http://thelegendofrandom.com/blog/sample-page

Comment: New link: http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/sample-page.html

Answer (score 15):

Here are the websites I know:

- [root-me](http://www.root-me.org/).
- [crackmes.one](https://crackmes.one/).
- [Over the Wire](http://www.overthewire.org/wargames/).
- [Le Hack](https://lehack.org/en).
- [Hacking Labs](https://www.hacking-lab.com/).
- [Smash the Stack](http://smashthestack.org/).
- [Matasano Microcorruption](https://microcorruption.com/login).
- [Matasano Crypto-challenge](http://cryptopals.com/).
- [Pentesterlab](https://pentesterlab.com/).
- [HackTheBox](https://www.hackthebox.eu/).

Answer (score 10):

I typed out this answer and then realized that you wanted *free* (as in beer) materials.  Minus 100 points for me.  This answer *assumes* that you want to learn how to reverse engineer in a software environment.

Under this assumption, and *assuming* you have a base understanding of a programming or scripting language, such as C/C++ or Python respectively, there are many, many topics to begin with to learn how to "reverse engineer" in a software environment.  A good first task for a beginner is to obtain a working knowledge of the [Assembly Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).  A good resource for this (at least for me) was the [Windows Debugging: Practical Foundations](http://astore.amazon.com/crasdumpanala-20/detail/1906717109) book by Dmitry Vostokov.  The book costs $14.

The objective of the book is to teach you how to use WinDbg to debug Windows Applications; however, along the way you will get an excellent, hands on introduction to the Assembly Language.

Please Note: I am in no way associated with Dmitry; however, I did buy the e-book.

Answer (score 8):

The classes by Dan Guido at http://pentest.cryptocity.net/ are pretty good too.  I used them as a reference when I first started getting into RE.  They cover a large subject area in addition to RE and are well taught.