# Advice on creating a reverse engineering introduction course?

Tags: x86, tools

I'm organizing an introduction to reverse engineering weekend class in my city and wanted to get some feedback and advice on how to structure it. I'm considering two 5 hour sessions.

The objective is for the students to be able to use linux tools and and reverse engineering tools (specifically radare2/GDB) to start doing CTFs and crackmes to practice. The target audience is software engineers, developers and students. Having said that and after a few conversations with potential participants, quality here is mediocre at best so I rather prepare for the worse and assume some participants won't even know the behind the scenes of a compilation process.

What I have so far is the following:

1. Linux usage
2. Memory map
3. Binary sections
4. Passing function arguments
5. Radare installation
6. Quick intro to x86 assembler
7. Gdb
8. Stacks - return address
9. stack canaries
10. Buffer overflows
11. Shellcode
12. Nop slides
13. CTF’s challenges

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this type of questions does not quite fit into the stack exchange model. It is better to use other means to find relevant and up-to-date references instead.

Answer (score 2):

*This type of questions does not quite fit into the stack exchange model. It is better to google for relevant and up-to-date references instead.*

*You can find an old similar question [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/265/where-to-find-free-training-in-reverse-engineering), and you can see the reasoning behind closing such questions [here](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-should-book-tutorial-questions-be-dealt-with).*

I advise against writing/planning something for yourself, as a lot of time and effort was put by others and there are plenty of existing reverse engineering introduction materials.

Here's a short list of tutorial repositories and collections, that seemed constantly maintained for a period of time and relevant at the time of writing (October 2016).

[Over 150 modules/articles (some include exercises) by the InfoSec Institute.](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/category/reverse-engineering-2/)

[A two day class created by Matt Briggs](http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroductionToReverseEngineering.html)

[Video presentations and exercises by Symantec](http://hackeracademy.com/library/reverse_engineering)